# Unable to read from offset 0 of a pointer in VST

Tags: c, verifiable-c

For various reasons I am verifying a program that attempts to read from a pointer with an offset of 0:

```
int x = (*(z + 0)).ssl_int;
```

When verifying this in VST, the context has as an assumption that there is a value on the heap at this location:

```
data_at Tsh (Tunion _sslval noattr) (inr x2) z
```

However, when trying to run `forward` over the read, the proof gets stuck with the error:

```
It is not obvious how to move forward here.  ...
```

But the same read goes through fine if I adjust my precondition to be

```
data_at Tsh (tarray (Tunion_sslval noattr) 1) [(inr x2)] z
```

or change the source code such that the read is instead:

```
int x = (*z).ssl_int;
```

Is there a way to verify this program without changing the source code or the program specification? How can I make the read go through?